# What is the exact use of a session variable in PHP ??? How is it different from a session ID?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = 'Alex';

?>
```

Is a PHP session varriable the session ID ?  if not , then what is the exact use of a session variable when we already have a unique session ID ???  Can someone please explain ? an example would help much !

Comment: I would suggest starting with this:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: A session is identified by a session ID, a "session variable" in PHP, is data bound to that session.  The ID is a unique identifier, data storage against that ID is what gives sessions any use.

Comment: @Orbling It is still very vague .. so what is the session variable exactly used for .. for example $_session['name'] = 'alex';

Comment: @SemirindiMakala: What do you consider the point of a session to be?  Generally, it is to uniquely identify a given browser of a website.  The session identifier is stored as a cookie (or occasionally in the URL) which the browser passes back with each request.  There is an array (usually) stored for each session in PHP, it automatically loads it in to `$_SESSION` when you call `session_start()`.  You can use it to store anything about the session you need to persist between calls.  Preferences, what they last did, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP uses the SID to recreate `$_SESSION` from the session storage.

Answer (score 2):

A session variable is just a variable stored in the session whereas the session id uniquely identifies a session for a specific user. (All session variables will be stored in the superglobal $_SESSION).

The session id will be stored as a cookie in your browser and is being sent to the server (as long as the cookie domain matches the requested server domain) for every request so that server knows which session belongs to your specific request.

In short: Sessions allow you to access and save data over several separate requests, which normally wouldn't be possible with a (mostly) stateless protocol such as http.

Further information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: @semirindi That second section basically says that every page they visit will allow you to access the same session variables. (Wouldn't have said anything, but I think this might be what they were looking for)

Answer (score 0):

A Session variable is simply for storing data that will be persistent until the session is killed or expires. For example many people use it for when a user logs into a website, you then store a session variable with the user's id and maybe some of their other info. Another time you might use it is if you have a multi-part form that is spread out over multiple pages. You can store data in the session until you are ready to finally store it in a database or do something else with it, without having to store the data in hidden input fields on every page.